# Jquery return error 500 (Internal Server Error) in a plugin wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to create a plugin Wordpress to get some informations from my services. In this first moment I just want to load a select with specialities.

I have a default Wordpress installed and in this is working as well, using Jquery 1.11. However when I installed this same plugin in another wordpress using Divi I got Internal Server Error from Jquery.

My ajax code:

```
var speciality = '';
var htmlSpec = '';
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/[path_plugin]/speciality.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
}).done(function(data) { 

    for(var spec in data){
        htmlSpec += '<option value='+spec+'>'+data[spec]+'</option>';
    }

    jQuery('select#specialities-list').append(htmlSpec);              
});
```

Error:

```
jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4 
GET [path_plugin]/speciality.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4
ajax @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4
(anonymous function) @ VM312:3
```

Does someone have any idea what I could do?

Comment: Can you please check logs of wordpress error? and post code of speciality.php and error which you getting...

Comment: As you are not sending any params so you can directly hit the URL from the browser and debug the problem in your php file as there is a problem with your php code not the jquery part

Comment: @AmanRawat I access my file directly from link and there is no error there.

Comment: @HareshVidja There is no error in my speciality.php, in this file it's just to encode a array to json.

Comment: Can you provide the output of the speciality.php

Comment: @AmanRawat this is the output [
"Allgemeinmedizin",
"Radiologie",
"Frauenheilkunde",
"Innere Medizin",
"Dermatologie",
"Analytische Psychologie",
"Zahnmedizin",
"Notfallmedizin",
"Allergologie",
"Augenheilkunde"
]

Comment: @Kelyane, if you access request url from browser, working correctlly and you receive same output?